# Keeping 12.04 Server updated properly

Tags: server, upgrade, 12.04, apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between apt-get upgrade and apt-get dist-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99033/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-upgrade-and-apt-get-dist-upgrade)

I just installed a copy of 12.04 Server and would like to know if I should use apt-get dist-upgrade to keep the server fully updated.

Apt-get update leaves the following behind; linux-headers-server, linux-image-server & linux-server.

Comment: You mean upgrade, not update, right?

Answer (score 0):

The three items not included with 'update' are a newer kernel.  This is optional, and could in theory cause issues.

I have already added to my test server (for 12.04 64bit) with no issues, but that could be different for your platform.

See:
[What is the difference between apt-get upgrade and apt-get dist-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99033/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-upgrade-and-apt-get-dist-upgrade)