# Why some applications updated and others are not?

Tags: updates, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I update applications without upgrading the whole OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95336/why-cant-i-update-applications-without-upgrading-the-whole-os)

Pues eso, me gustaría conocer el motivo por el que hay aplicaciones que se actualizan (por ejemplo firefox, thunderbird, chromium, etc.) y hay otras aplicaciones que no reciben la última actualización de los mismos (como transmission, libreoffice, Gimp, xfce 4.10 etc.)

Actualmente uso Xubuntu 11.10 y Xubuntu 12.04, pero creo que esto sucede en todas las versiones.

```
                            Translation via SpanishDict
```

I would like to know the reason why there are applications that are updated (e.g. firefox, thunderbird, chromium, etc.) and there are other applications that do not receive the latest update of the same (such as transmission, PRI, Gimp, xfce 4.10 etc.)

Currently I'm using Xubuntu 11.10 and Xubuntu 12.04, But I think this happens in all versions.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Kindly help us assist you by translating this to English. You may use [Google translate](http://translate.google.com) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It may help for you to read about [Ubuntu repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu).  Some packages are fully supported ("main", "restricted" repos); some packages are not ("universe", "multiverse").  Also, please read the [Ubuntu Updates section](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Ubuntu_Updates).  Updates are primarily used for fixing security vulnerabilities and serious bugs.  It may be that the packages you are seeing updated have more vulnerabilities/bugs than the ones you aren't seeing updated.

The rate of updates also depends on how quickly vulnerabilities/bugs are being fixed in the upstream codebase and the priority the package is given within Ubuntu.  E.g. since Unity is the primary Ubuntu desktop and it is a relatively new project (vs. e.g. XFCE), you will probably see more Unity-related updates than updates for other window managers.