# Ubuntu not installing newest version of apps?

Tags: gimp, blender

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do software updates work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9346/how-do-software-updates-work)

Hi I just installed blender and gimp only to find that it is installing older versions not the newest versions.

It installed gimp 2.6 rather than gimp 2.8 and blender 2.62 rather than 2.63a

How do I update them, I'm finding that its extremely hard to use the command line to install anything and there are no .deb files on their websites.

---

Ubuntu should really fix this as new users like myself just expect to get the newest versions, even when i updated with the update manager it still won't install the newest versions. I had to use command line which is very hard.
There is nothing wrong with making Ubuntu easier!.

Answer (score 0):

This question has basically been asked before. You can find answer here: [How Do Software Updates Work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9346/how-do-software-updates-work)

[Ubuntu Stable Release Updates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates)

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu 12.04 does not have packages for gimp 2.8 and blender 2.63a

You can search for available versions here:

http://packages.ubuntu.com

In the next release of ubuntu is gimp 2.8 included ([http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gimp](http://packages.ubuntu.com))

Comment: Ubuntu should work on fixing this, as new users like me have no idea why its not.

Answer (score 0):

Generally new versions of packages do not get added to repositories.

[Why some applications updated and others are not?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134933/why-some-applications-updated-and-others-are-not)

There is a PPA for gimp - [How do I get the latest GIMP version available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134035/how-do-i-get-gimp-2-8)

Look here for a how-to install latest blender - https://askubuntu.com/a/112183/2018

I can;t find a PPA for blender.

Answer (score 0):

I know for GIMP, you have to install the ppa; e.g. as per the instructions in http://www.unixmen.com/gimp-2-8-is-out-ppa-ubuntu/. Once you've installed the ppa, run sudo apt-get update and then sudo apt-get install gimp. That's all, nothing hard...

For blender, here's the launchpad ppa: https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/blender and then continue like described above.

AFAIK this is because the latest versions are not yet in the official repositories.

For a way without cli:

- open 'Software Sources', in the tab 'Other Software', press 'add' and copy/paste the ppa addresses found on the websites above and then 'add source'.
- now open 'Synaptic Package Manager' or 'Ubuntu Software Center', first press 'Reload' and then search and install your apps.

Hope this answers your question...