# Whom should I ask to update a package to a new upstream release?

Tags: package-management, launchpad, bug-reporting, upstream

Whom should I ask for upgrading the particular package, if there is a new upstream release?

Should I file a bug report?

What if the package is maintained by Debian maintainers? Should I leave a comment at their mailing list?

Comment: See [What can I do if Synaptic can't get the latest version of software?](http://askubuntu.com/a/234255/25656) and [Why can't I update applications without upgrading the whole OS?](http://askubuntu.com/a/95586/25656) to understand the policy relating to updating software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maintainer of the package. He might already be working on it!

How? Doesn't really matter. I see bug reports for it, but usually this is discussed behind the scenes. I guess most is being discussed using IRC and mailing lists. Depends on the package and the people working on it.

Debian/Ubuntu developers (package maintainers) are uploading new releases to `experimental`/`unstable` and will end up later in a stable channel via regular QA process. A new upstream release isn't usually going to be included in a stable release. Security or severe bugs come as regular updates, without backporting a whole new release.

Exception: web browsers.

See also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/95350/88802) on the policy regarding updates within Ubuntu.