# How do I install Python 3.3?

Tags: software-installation, python3

I have downloaded Python 3.3 from the official site but no idea how to install it.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: [Why can't I update applications without upgrading the whole OS?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/95336/why-cant-i-update-applications-without-upgrading-the-whole-os) explains *why* it's not available. In short: other packages are relying on an older (still maintained!) version. And please keep your personal thoughts about how this site works for yourself or post it on [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/) where you can post once you've gained [enough reputation points](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/participate-in-meta). But first: [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) on how the site works.

Answer (score 115):

Python 3.3 has been released on 29 September 2012, several months *after* Ubuntu 12.04 was released. It is included in Ubuntu 12.10 though as `python3.3` package

If you want to install Python 3.3 on Ubuntu version which does not have it in its repositories, you have the following options:

**Use a PPA**

There's a PPA containing [Old and New Python versions](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes) maintained by Felix Krull. See [Luper Rouch's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/290283/176889) for installation instructions.

**Compile Python from source**

This is very easy and allows you to have multiple Python versions without messing with system python interpreter (which is used by a lot of Ubuntu own programs). On my dev machine I have literally dozens of different Python versions from 2.4 to 3.2 living happily in `/opt`.

we need C compiler and other stuff to compile Python

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

SQLite libs need to be installed in order for Python to have SQLite support.

```bash
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 # for the command-line client
sudo apt-get install bzip2 libbz2-dev
```

Download and compile Python:

```
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.5/Python-3.3.5.tar.xz
tar xJf ./Python-3.3.5.tar.xz
cd ./Python-3.3.5
./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.3
make && sudo make install
```

Some nice touches to install a `py` command by creating a symlink:

```bash
mkdir ~/bin
ln -s /opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3 ~/bin/py
```

Alternatively, you can install a bash alias named `py` instead:

```bash
echo 'alias py="/opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3"' >> .bashrc
```

And this is it. Now you can have *any* Python version, even an alpha, or, say, to have a few copies of Python 3.3 compiled with different settings... not that many people need that though :)

**Use pyenv**

There's a software called [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) which may help you to automate the procedure - what it essentially does is compile Python from source, installing it in your home directory. Its goal is to help you manage multiple Python versions.

Comment: After installation, how would one *use* this alternative Python installation? Say I have some `.py` files with the `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang line (executable bit set), how would I make them to use this installation in `/opt/python3.3` without modifying all of them? Or even system-installed ones.

Comment: @gertvdijk: the whole point is *not* to replace the default interpreter - if you do that, then *every* python app ran from your account will use Python 3.3, including Ubuntu apps, such as Software Centre ect. We don't want that. To run a script, just use `py myscript.py` (where `py` is a symlink we've created at the end of the exercise). I also normally use virtualenv or buildout for my projects.

Comment: @gertvdijk You can keep multiple python environments manageable using virtualenv.

Comment: @gertvdijk Are you aware that python 3.x and python 2.x are incompatible?  If you were to point all your existing scripts at python 3.3 they'd probably break.  Simply shebang your new python scripts as #! /opt/python3.3 and the correct interpreter will be addressed when you run it.

Comment: @TonyMartin Yes, I'm totally aware of it and just pretended not to know this. I develop stuff in Python. :) My comment was merely a way to get this into the answer as well. Some people might expect it to be replaced.

Comment: @gertvdijk then I'll leave my comment for the same readers. :-)

Comment: `mkdir ~/bin
ln -s /opt/python3.3/bin/python ~/bin/py` doesn't work for me. 

I found that `/opt/python3.3/bin/python` should be `/opt/python3.3/bin/python3`, but still getting `py: command not found`. Any suggestions.

Comment: @TamilVendhan: if you didn't have `~/bin` before you need to log out and then log back in for the directory to be added to PATH.

Comment: On Ubuntu 13 it's `/opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3`

Comment: These instructions also work for Python 2.7.5 on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: @Nick: yes, they should work for any Python version with only minor modifications (changing the version in the pathnames)

Comment: @Nick Based partly on Sergey's answer and my own experience, I have written a script in the answer further below that automates the whole process, and it should be useful for any Python version.

Comment: After building Python3.3, we can create a Python3.3 virtualenv by `mkvirtualenv -p /opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3`

Comment: [Pythobrew is deprecated](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew#deprecated), use [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) instead.

Comment: From my experience, downloading python and compiling from source beats all other alternatives.

Comment: Excellent answer (+1). It's already mentioned in the comments, but I'd mention explicitly that users that don't have the directory `~/bin` already should add it to the `PATH` (making sure it's in the right place of course).

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Last time I checked Ubuntu was adding `~/bin` to PATH automatically on login if present. So all you need is to log out and then log in back to have it added. I mentioned it in the comments above a couple of years ago :)

Comment: @Sergey Thanks. It definitely seems to do this for normal users. (I just tried.) Personally, I find this astonishing: this should never have happened. Mind you, I _do_ have a `${HOME}/bin` directory but I don't think an OS should have put such directory in a user's path.

Comment: Modern versions of Python have pip included inside, so if you want it too, you should `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`, or else Python will be compiled without pip.

Comment: I'd personnally not choose `/opt/` for the installation directory, since it is supposed to be for self-contained third party applications. `/usr/local` should be used instead, and that's the default of `./configure`, so why not leaving the default?

Comment: Does is work for debian?

Answer (score 43):

Here is what I did to install Python 3.3 on Ubuntu 12.04:

1. Install dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep python3.2
   sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev libssl1.0.0 tk8.5-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
   ```
2. Download Python 3.3.0:

   ```
   wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.3.0/Python-3.3.0.tgz
   ```
3. Extract:

   ```
   tar xvfz Python-3.3.0.tgz
   ```
4. Configure and Install:

   ```
   cd Python-3.3.0
   ./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.3
   make  
   sudo make install
   ```
5. Test if it worked:

   ```
   /opt/python3.3/bin/python3
   ```

You should see something similar:

```
Python 3.3.0 (default, Jan 31 2013, 18:37:42) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Some Additional things that are useful... you can create a virtual environment in your home and just activate Python 3.3 on demand..

1. Create a Virtual Environment in your home:

   ```
   /opt/python3.3/bin/pyvenv ~/py33
   ```
2. Activate the virtualenv:

   ```
   source ~/py33/bin/activate
   ```
3. Install distribute tools:

   ```
   wget http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
   python distribute_setup.py
   ```
4. Install pip:

   ```
   easy_install pip
   ```
5. Install any python packages you want (i.e. bottle)

   ```
   pip install bottle
   ```

Enjoy!

Comment: `sudo apt-get build-dep python3.2`? You probably forgot `install` in between :)

Comment: @StamKaly : nope. `build-dep` is not a package, it's an `apt-get` **verb** (like `install`). It means "_install all packages necessary to build the requested source package(s)_"

Answer (score 36):

The [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) has packages for old and new python versions:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.3
```

Comment: Yes, that installed something alright, but how do I invoke it? Typing 'python' gives methe python 2 interpreter and typing 'python3' suggest that its not installed and can be installed from ubuntu repos.

Comment: Ah..I see the executable is called python3.3 (or pythonX.Y, for whatever version of python installed :-)

Comment: ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes is archived. Use ppa:deadsnakes/ppa instead.

Answer (score 10):

**Ubuntu 14.04 and earlier:**

Python2.7 comes default, Use the package manager to install python3 on top of regular python on Ubuntu, Ubuntu can handle both 2.7 and 3.2 at the same time without a virtualenv:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
python3 --version
Python 3.2.3
python --version
Python 2.2.3
```

**Ubuntu 18.04:**

Python3 comes default with the OS and Python2.7 isn't available unless you specifically install.

Three package names to choose from: `python`, `python-minimal`, `python-all`.  Default is minimal.  These words are just flags to the Ubuntu repositories to include extra stuff or not.  To see exactly what subpackages are and aren't included, drill down on the subpackages of: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python

```
sudo apt install python-minimal
python --version
```

Or to try to upgrade the python3:

```
sudo apt install python3-minimal
python --version
```

To try to force a specific version, you can try passing a version parameter:

```
sudo apt-get install python 3.3.3
```

Comment: How do you update the python3 version from 3.2.3 to 3.3.5?

Comment: Python 3.3 is only available from the default repositories in Ubuntu 12.10 and later. OP is using 12.04

Comment: If you want more than 2 versions of python available on one computer (other than the default 2.7 and 3.2 that your OS chooses for you), then each new version of python should be in its own virtual environment (`virtualenv`).  Google search: "Use virtualenv to isolate version of python".  If you don't use some kind of container, then you expose yourself to a labyrinth of problems since python takes a giant shit all over your computer, occupying every nook and cranny, and they fight each other in John Cleeseian fashion.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning**: Pythonbrew has been deprecated in favor of pyenv. Updated instructions are [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333109/upgrading-to-python-2-7-5-on-ubuntu-12-04/333111#333111)

Also you can use something like [pythonbrew](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew):

```
curl -kL http://xrl.us/pythonbrewinstall | bash    
echo "[[ -s $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc ]] && source $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc" >> ~/.bashrc    
pythonbrew install 3.3
```

It's quite easy to use, and another benefit, that it's possible to install any python version you need. Please see their [docs](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew#readme) for mode details

Answer (score 1):

I have written a script to automate all of the downloading, compiling and installing of non-package Python versions. The script installs the Python version in `/opt` safely away from the package manager and system versions of Python.

It even fetches the dependencies as well for most versions of Ubuntu. It should work on all currently supported Ubuntu versions (10.04, 12.04, 12.10, and 13.04), and probably on other versions.

I include it below, and have posted it also at [my Github repository](https://github.com/Exactus29/bash_scripts_libraries/blob/master/build_python), which is the master location.

The script should be copied and saved into a text editor as, for example, `build_python`, and made executable (`chmod u+x build_python`) and then can be run with two parameters, where the first parameter must always be the Python branch, and the second parameter must always be the Python version.

See [python.org](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/) for the listings for the version you wish to compile.

Here are a couple of example of the script's usage:

1. For the stable release, after having checked the listings, it can be run as

   ```
   ./build_python '3.3.2' '3.3.2'
   ```
2. For the development release, where the two parameters are different in the listings, it can be run as:

   ```
   ./build_python '3.4.0' '3.4.0a1'
   ```

The body of the script is reproduced below (no syntax highlighting here. For that, see my [Github page](https://github.com/Exactus29/bash_scripts_libraries/blob/master/build_python):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# by mik, aka Exactus29, https://github.com/Exactus29
# 
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.

# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.

# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

##########

# a script to compile the latest stable version of Python and place in /opt

(( $# == 2 )) || { printf "Please provide a version branch (e.g. 3.4.0) and a version release (e.g. 3.4.0a1) in that order.\n"
                   printf "The official site is python.org, see the ftp server at: http://python.org/ftp/python.\n" >&2 ; exit 1; }

# a splew of variables, so that just the version number can be given on the cmd line
# and then then the script can do the rest, including verifying the packages using gpg

# need different branch and version as sometimes the two are different, particularly for dev releases
py_branch="$1"
py_version="$2"
shift 2

# check if install target already exists in /opt, and exit so user can decide what to do
if [[ -d /opt/python-${py_version} ]]; then 
    printf "Target directory for the build already exists, please rename or remove.\n" >&2
    exit 1
else 
    :
fi

# use tar.bz2 as that is what most of the older releases used, i.e. in case user tries to build an older release
py_url="http://python.org/ftp/python/${py_branch}/Python-${py_version}.tar.bz2"
py_asc="http://python.org/ftp/python/${py_branch}/Python-${py_version}.tar.bz2.asc"
py_dir="$HOME/src/python_build" # checked to exist later, etc

# first check if user requested file exists on server
wget --spider ${py_url} >/dev/null 2>&1
(( $? > 0 )) && printf "No such version, version ${py_version} does not exist\n" >&2 && exit 1


# now very important before we do anything else, to check if asc file exists, as it  doesn't for some downloads
# if we don't check and it doesn't exist it causes the script to exit

wget --spider ${py_asc} >/dev/null 2>&1
# set a flag re whether asc file exists, so can check later and avoid problems
(( $? > 0 )) && no_asc=1 || no_asc=0

# set up more variables
py_tarbz2="${py_url##*/}"
(( no_asc == 0 )) && py_tarbz2_asc="${py_asc##*/}" # only set this if there is an asc file
py_folder="${py_tarbz2%.*.*}"
py_gpg_key="" 

# check other build dependencies are installed, beyond build-dep, sqlite support, readline, ncurses, build-essential 
dependencies_check() {

    local installed=()
    local to_be_installed=()
    local dependencies_list=(build-essential wget libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev libssl1.0.0 tk8.5-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev)    

    for package in "${dependencies_list[@]}"; do 
        if grep -iq '^ii' < <(dpkg -l "$package"); then
            installed+=("$package")
        else 
            to_be_installed+=("$package")
        fi
    done 2>/dev/null

    if (( ${#to_be_installed[@]} > 0 )); then
        printf "If you have recently elevated your privileges with sudo, you will not see a " 
        printf "prompt here, before the apt-get update and install of packages occurs.\n" 
        sleep 2
        sudo -p "We need to install some dependencies, please enter your password: " apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install "${to_be_installed[@]}"
        return 0
    else 
        printf "\nNothing to install, proceeding.\n"
        return 0
    fi

}

# tailor build-dep to new python version we want to build, basically either 2x or 3x versions
# should work with at least lucid/precise/quantal/raring/saucy, the currently supported versions
if (( ${py_branch:0:1} == 3 )) && grep -iq 'precise' /etc/lsb-release 2>/dev/null; then
    sudo -p "Please provide your password to install dependencies: " apt-get build-dep python3.2 && dependencies_check
elif (( ${py_branch:0:1} == 3 )) && grep -Eiq '(raring|quantal|saucy)' /etc/lsb-release 2>/dev/null; then
    sudo -p "Please provide your password to install dependencies: " apt-get build-dep python3.3 && dependencies_check
elif [[ ${py_branch:0:3} == 2.7 ]] && grep -iq 'lucid' /etc/lsb-release 2>/dev/null; then
    sudo -p "Please provide your password to install dependencies: " apt-get build-dep python2.6 && dependencies_check
elif [[ ${py_branch:0:3} == 2.7 ]]; then
    sudo -p "Please provide your password to install dependencies: " apt-get build-dep python2.7 && dependencies_check
else
    printf "\nProceeding, but make sure you have the correct build deps installed.\n\n"
    sleep 2        
fi

# dir checks
if [[ -d $HOME/src ]]; then 
    cd $HOME/src || exit 1
else
    mkdir $HOME/src && cd $HOME/src
fi

if [[ -d ${py_dir} ]]; then
    mv "${py_dir}" "${py_dir}_old_$(date '+%F_%H_%M_%S')"
    mkdir "${py_dir##*/}" && cd "${py_dir##*/}"
else
    mkdir "${py_dir##*/}" && cd "${py_dir##*/}"
fi

# finally, download python 
printf "\nNow downloading version ${py_version} from branch ${py_branch} ....."
wget "${py_url}" -P "${py_dir}" >/dev/null 2>&1
(( $? == 0 )) && printf "Done.\n"
# only download asc if it exists, set flag earlier
(( no_asc == 0 )) && wget "${py_asc}" -P "${py_dir}" >/dev/null 2>&1

# gpg tests

gpg_test() {
    # if error returned, extract gpg key from error message
    py_gpg_key="$(gpg --verify "${py_tarbz2_asc}" "${py_tarbz2}" 2>&1 | awk '{ print $NF }' | grep -v found)"

    # now check with gpg_key (should be Python release signing key)
    printf "\nReceiving keys.. "
    gpg --recv-keys "${py_gpg_key}" >/dev/null 2>&1
    (( $? > 0)) && printf "Key could not be received\n" || printf "Done.\n"

    printf "\nVerifying download... "
    gpg --verify "${py_tarbz2_asc}" "${py_tarbz2}" >/dev/null 2>&1
    (( $? > 0 )) && printf "The download could not be verified.\n" || printf "Done.\n"

}

if (( no_asc == 0 )); then
    gpg --verify "${py_tarbz2_asc}" "${py_tarbz2}" >/dev/null 2>&1
    if (( $? > 0 )); then 
        gpg_test 
    else
        printf "\nDownload verified\n\n"
    fi
else
    printf "\nProceeding even though asc file is not available for gpg to verify download\n\n"
    sleep 1
fi

# unpack and cd to the python folder
printf "Unpacking archive...."
tar xvjf "${py_folder}.tar.bz2" >/dev/null 2>&1
(( $? == 0 )) && printf "Done.\n" || { printf "Problems occured when unpacking, exiting\n" >&2; exit 1; }
cd "${py_folder}" || exit 1

# tailor the build to your machine here with configure and make

printf "\nNow for the configure (default prefix is /opt/python-${py_version})...."
sleep 2
./configure --prefix=/opt/python-${py_version} >/dev/null 2>&1
# as configure and make will exit anyway on error, no need to add || alternatives to the tests below
(( $? == 0 )) && printf "Done.\n\n"  
sleep 1

printf "\nNow for the compile. (If necessary, please add your own specifications to the make command line and run the script again)\n"
printf "\nPlease wait for the compile to finish: it may take a while...."
make >/dev/null 2>&1
(( $? == 0 )) && printf "Done.\n\n"

printf "\nWe are installing with make install into /opt, instead of using checkinstall.\n"
sudo make install >/dev/null 2>&1
installcode=$?
(( $installcode == 0 )) && printf "\n${py_version} succesfully installed in /opt/python-${py_version}\n\n"

if [[ -d $HOME/bin ]]; then
    ln -s /opt/python-${py_version}/bin/python${py_version:0:3} ~/bin/py-${py_version}
    (( $? == 0 )) && printf "\nSymlink created, run py-${py_version} in the terminal to launch the interpreter\n"
else
    mkdir $HOME/bin && ln -s /opt/python-${py_version}/bin/python${py_version:0:3} ~/bin/py-${py_version}
    (( $? == 0 )) && printf "\nSymlink created, run py-${py_version} in the terminal to launch the interpreter\n"
    printf "\nHowever, you will not be able to call py-${py_version} until you have logged out and in again, as bin will not"
    printf " have been added to your path just as $HOME/bin is created.\nn"
fi

# important info re setting up pyvenv re distribute tools and pip etc
cat <<extra_info

            See also a program called pyvenv with your installation in /opt, 
            with which you can create a virtual environment and use tools
            such as pip, etc. See the official documentation at:
            http://docs.python.org/3.3/using/scripts.html#pyvenv-creating-virtual-environments

extra_info

sleep 2 
exit ${installcode}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is interested, I wrote a more verbose step-by-step article on how to install Python 3.3.2 locally from source on Ubuntu 12.04, mostly based on reading @sergey's excellent answer above: http://nicholsonjf.com/blog/install-python3-locally-from-source

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that I followed:

```
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.3.2/Python-3.3.2.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf ./Python-3.3.2.tar.bz2
cd ./Python-3.3.2
./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.3
make && make install
mkdir ~/bin
ln -s /opt/python3.3/bin/python ~/bin/py
echo 'alias py="/opt/python3.3/bin/python3"' >> .bashrc
```