# How to install python 3.2 in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, 13.04, python

I need python 3.2 for development purposes, but new ubuntu 13.04 comes with python 3.3.

is there any best practice for installing older python version into ubuntu?

Thanks

Comment: Any specific reason you'd need 3.2? Is there a feature in it which is not in 3.3?

Comment: No, but there is 3.2 on the production server and I would like to work on the same version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [Deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes), which includes a range of Python versions packaged for a range of Ubuntu versions, including 3.2 for raring.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.2
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was waiting for.. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Download and compile Python (with the terminal):

```
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.3.0/Python-3.3.0.tar.bz2
tar jxf ./Python-3.3.0.tar.bz2
cd ./Python-3.3.0
./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.3
make && sudo make install
```

Source: [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-to-install-python-3-3)

Comment: If I overlook that I want to install 3.2 (not 3.3), I guess this answer should be "compile it". I am ok, with this answer, but I would like to know if there is any better option - prepared packages maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Other options I've come across are [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) and [pythonz](https://github.com/saghul/pythonz) - they both will build custom versions of python (including PyPy and Jython) for you and allow you to change the python you use in the terminal.

I haven't tried either myself so can't recommend one.