# How do I install Python 3.2 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: python

The default version that Ubuntu carries is Python 2.7 and Python 3.4. How do I get Python 3.2?

There another [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295937/how-to-install-python-3-2-in-ubuntu-13-04) on this website where the topranked answer solves the issue for Ubuntu 13.04 with

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
```

If I try that I get the error:

```
sudo: apt-add-repository: command not found
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install python 3.2 in ubuntu 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/295937/how-to-install-python-3-2-in-ubuntu-13-04)

Comment: Whats the output of `sudo grep 'secure_path' /etc/sudoers` and `type -a  apt-add-repository` ?

Comment: @heemayl :  type -a apt-add-repository
-bash: type: apt-add-repository: not found

Comment: Do `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common` and then check..

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work by first installing "software-properties-common" as suggested in the comments:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.2
```