# Installing IDLE (using Python 3.3.2) in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt, software-center, python

I am trying to install the text editor IDLE using Python 3.3.2
in Ubuntu 12.04, but from the Ubuntu Software Centre I have been told that there is no  package called idle-python 3.3 from current software sources.

Does this mean that it is not possible to install for Ubuntu 12.04? Could I update those sources to include that package (idle-python 3.3) for Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: In the terminal run `sudo apt-get install idle3`. If you are not sure about the name of a package you can run `apt-cache search <string>` which will look for packages which contains `<string>` in their names or descriptions.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-to-install-python-3-3)

Answer (score 4):

In the terminal run

```
sudo apt-get install idle3
```

(The right package name for IDLE with Python 3 is `idle3` I think you can check it Software Center.)

If you are not sure about the name of a package you can run `apt-cache search <string>` which will look for packages which contains `<string>` in their names or descriptions.

**Edit:**

To use Python 3.3 in 12.04:

- You can try bootstrapping Raring/Saucy. See [pbuilder HowTo](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PbuilderHowto). (*Kind of complicated*, but very good.)
- Or you can try installing Debian+Xfce testing or Xubuntu 13.04 in VirtualBox. (This depends on your system capabilities, that's why I recommend a lightweight DE.)
- You can even try building Python 3.3 from source and installing it in a folder of your preference, but don't know how much effort this would take.

Of course, the most 'trivial' alternative would be to upgrade from Precise to Raring. Specially good if you can backup your important data and do a clean install.

Comment: Yes, I installed idle 3, but in the python shell is indicated as default version 3.2.3 but I downloaded and built the 3.3.2.                            It will work the shell with this last version anyway?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you were talking about a non (yet) official version of Python (at least for Ubuntu 12.04). You should upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04 or get comfortable with Python 3.2. Either way, why do you need to use Python 3.3??

Comment: It is no essential, but it is the version asked in one course on-line of Coursera.It is about lineal algebra using Python and the course especifies Python 3.3.2.Would it be unimportant this detail?                         On the other hand,is there any other Python editor from where to configure the wished version?

Comment: To the first question, I don't think there's any importance in this detail (unless the course is about Python internals and advanced stuff), anyway you should ask the course staff. To the second question you can try bootstrapping Raring/Saucy: [PBuilder HowTo](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PbuilderHowto). Or you can try installing Debian testing or Xubuntu 13.04 in VirtualBox.