# Running python3.3 using virtulenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, zlib

I am using Ubuntu server 12.04. The default python version is 2.7. I have installed python 3.3 in `/opt directory`. When I tried to create a virtualenv to use python 3.3, I get the following error:

```
$ virtualenv -p /opt/python3.3/bin/python3 python3_env
Running virtualenv with interpreter `/opt/python3.3/bin/python3`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File `usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py`, line 17, in 
`import zlib`
 ImportError: No module named 'zlib'
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I would recommend using `deadsnakes ppa` [How do I install Python 3.3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-to-install-python-3-3)

What you need to understand is your `virtualenv` package should be compatible with python3. I.e.`virtualenv` should be installed with python3.3. This can be done with `easy_install` OR `pip` compatible with python3.3.

Or

Also python3.3 comes with [inbuilt virtualenv](http://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) which can be used as

`python3.3 -m venv VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME`

`pyvenv VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME`

These binaries may be in `/opt`. So you may require full path.