# howto link / execute / add to $PATH: python3.3.5 after manual installation in 12.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, python, python3, bashrc

I'm trying to install python3.3.5 on /home/myUser/XX, where home is located on a separate partition.
I'm relatively new to Linux and have only basic knowledge about installing packages on my own, without the synaptic package Manager.

**Here is what I did:**
I followed the instructions from [Sergey](https://askubuntu.com/users/14564/sergey) in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-to-install-python-3-3). I also used the similar explanation from [James Nichsolson](https://askubuntu.com/users/185306/james-nicholson) at this [webpage](http://nicholsonjf.com/blog/install-python3-locally-from-source)

Everything worked fine so far except this part:

> Some nice touches to install a py command by creating a symlink:
>
> ```
> mkdir ~/bin
> ln -s /opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3 ~/bin/py
> ```

As I understand it, this is to make python3.3 execuable via the terminal at any place? So if I write python3.3 it opens.

my paths are bit different from the ones in Sergeys description:
path of python installation:

```
/home/metin/python/python3.3.5
```

my ./configure command was therefore:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/metin/python/python3.3.5
```

my command to create the link was:

```
 ln -s /home/metin/python/python3.3.5/bin/python3.3
```

**Problem:**

after I do this and when I type python3 in my terminal it says this programm is not installed, so something went wrong with creating the link?

**Further Question:**

Where is the difference between creating such a link and adding entries to $PATH? As I understand it Ubuntu can access all programs stored in $PATH, right? Why should'nt I just ad .../python3.3.5 to $PATH? So when do I use ln(links) and when do I add stuff to $PATH.

If I want to add dirs to $PATH how do I do that easy? I found some explanations on the internet but I'm confused. There is the file .bashrc in my /home dir. Is that the one were I add such dirs? Because there is also /etc/bash.bashrc and I remember adding

```
PATH=/home/metin/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH
MANPATH=/home/metin/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH
INFOPATH=/home/metin/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH
```

when I installed texlive

since this questions are related I found it logic to put it all in one thread. Please let me know if I should rather make more than one post.

Comment: Let's start from the beginning first: Why do you want to install python3 manually when you have `sudo apt-get install python3`?

Comment: The synaptics tells me that the newest version available for autom. install is 3.2.x. I want to have 3.3.5 so I thought the only way will be to do it manualy (maybe 12.04 LTS not released 3.3.5 yet?) -> Furthermore I need to learn Linux/handling Linux, so anything is a good exercise :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo ln -s /home/metin/python/python3.3.5/bin/python3.3 /usr/bin/python3.3.5
```

Not sure if your home path is correct, so if the command above fails you must symlink the binary located in your home folder to /usr/bin.

Comment: to get started with python I now installed 3.2 via synaptics (package `python3`) will this interfere with my own installed python 3.3.5 (because in the 3.3.5/bin dir the execs name is also python3)

Comment: Probably no, there are many versions that can be installed at once in your system. But you can test it typing `python -V` in console and see the version

Comment: optimal case would be: I type python3.3.5 in terminal (anywhere) and it fires up python3.3.5 which I installed myself. Because right now it would fire up the synaptics python3 (python3.2) when I type `python3`. When I type `python -V` it gives me the 2.7 Version

Comment: I forgot you are using python3, sorry. But if you symlinked your home python as python3.3.5 there is no problem, python3 installed via synaptic will work properly

Comment: ok it works, the original idea to do this at /home (diff partition), that I could install ubuntu new and keep everything on my /home partition. If I do this now, the links will be dead after reinstall right?

Comment: Yes, after reinstall you must symlink all again.

Comment: aren’t then the entries in $PATH stored in my `.bashrc` at `/home/` a more permanent way to store a directory to search for a program? This would last after a new installation of the `/` partition?

Comment: You are right, if you change your path in .bashrc it will survive a reinstall, but: it will only work in bash from a terminal (not from other shells or the GUI) and it will only work for your user.