# Is it possible to downgrade the default version of Python from my Ubuntu installation?

Tags: python, software-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 which comes with Python 3.4 installed by default. But I wish to downgrade it to Python 3.3 for my needs. However, when I try to remove it, it also wants to remove other packages along with it which seem to be using Python.

Is it possible to safely downgrade the default version of Python? What other options do I have in this regard?

Comment: Have a look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-do-i-install-python-3-3

Comment: Why don't install another Python alongside Python 3.4 and change the reference of the symbolic link `/usr/bin/python/`?