# 3G modem on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mobile-broadband, wvdial

Both my 3G modems ([Uknown](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NetworkManager/Hardware/3G) in this table) doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04. I tried SIM card push to 3G slot in notebook Dell D630 and also with external 3G modem card. Seme effect: broadband network I can create, but this network is not available after creating. Restarting service network-manager doesn't work also.

`/etc/wvdial.conf` is empty.

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1b1c:1a03 Corsair 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 413c:8140 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 360 Bluetooth
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 04f3:02f4 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 2.4G Cordless Mouse
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 0b97:7761 O2 Micro, Inc. Oz776 1.1 Hub
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 0483:2016 SGS Thomson Microelectronics Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 004: ID 0b97:7772 O2 Micro, Inc. OZ776 CCID Smartcard Reader
```

lshal:

```
udi = '/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_b97_7772_noserial'
  info.linux.driver = 'usb'  (string)
  info.parent = '/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_b97_7761_noserial'  (string)
  info.product = 'OZ776 CCID Smartcard Reader'  (string)
  info.subsystem = 'usb_device'  (string)
  info.udi = '/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_b97_7772_noserial'  (string)
  info.vendor = 'O2 Micro, Inc.'  (string)
  linux.device_file = '/dev/bus/usb/007/004'  (string)
  linux.hotplug_type = 2  (0x2)  (int)
  linux.subsystem = 'usb'  (string)
  linux.sysfs_path = '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb7/7-1/7-1.2'  (string)
  usb_device.bus_number = 7  (0x7)  (int)
  usb_device.can_wake_up = true  (bool)
  usb_device.configuration_value = 1  (0x1)  (int)
  usb_device.device_class = 0  (0x0)  (int)
  usb_device.device_protocol = 0  (0x0)  (int)
  usb_device.device_revision_bcd = 272  (0x110)  (int)
  usb_device.device_subclass = 0  (0x0)  (int)
  usb_device.is_self_powered = true  (bool)
  usb_device.linux.device_number = 4  (0x4)  (int)
  usb_device.linux.sysfs_path = '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb7/7-1/7-1.2'  (string)
  usb_device.max_power = 0  (0x0)  (int)
  usb_device.num_configurations = 1  (0x1)  (int)
  usb_device.num_interfaces = 1  (0x1)  (int)
  usb_device.num_ports = 0  (0x0)  (int)
  usb_device.product = 'OZ776 CCID Smartcard Reader'  (string)
  usb_device.product_id = 30578  (0x7772)  (int)
  usb_device.speed = 12.0 (12) (double)
  usb_device.vendor = 'O2 Micro, Inc.'  (string)
  usb_device.vendor_id = 2967  (0xb97)  (int)
  usb_device.version = 1.1 (1.1) (double)


udi = '/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_b97_7761_noserial'
  info.linux.driver = 'usb'  (string)
  info.parent = '/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_1d6b_1_0000_00_1d_2'  (string)
  info.product = 'Oz776 1.1 Hub'  (string)
  info.subsystem = 'usb_device'  (string)
  info.udi = '/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_b97_7761_noserial'  (string)
  info.vendor = 'O2 Micro, Inc.'  (string)
  linux.device_file = '/dev/bus/usb/007/002'  (string)
  linux.hotplug_type = 2  (0x2)  (int)
  linux.subsystem = 'usb'  (string)
  linux.sysfs_path = '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb7/7-1'  (string)
  usb_device.bus_number = 7  (0x7)  (int)
  usb_device.can_wake_up = true  (bool)
  usb_device.configuration_value = 1  (0x1)  (int)
  usb_device.device_class = 9  (0x9)  (int)
  usb_device.device_protocol = 0  (0x0)  (int)
  usb_device.device_revision_bcd = 272  (0x110)  (int)
  usb_device.device_subclass = 0  (0x0)  (int)
  usb_device.is_self_powered = true  (bool)
  usb_device.linux.device_number = 2  (0x2)  (int)
  usb_device.linux.sysfs_path = '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb7/7-1'  (string)
  usb_device.max_power = 2  (0x2)  (int)
  usb_device.num_configurations = 1  (0x1)  (int)
  usb_device.num_interfaces = 1  (0x1)  (int)
  usb_device.num_ports = 4  (0x4)  (int)
  usb_device.product = 'Oz776 1.1 Hub'  (string)
  usb_device.product_id = 30561  (0x7761)  (int)
  usb_device.speed = 12.0 (12) (double)
  usb_device.vendor = 'O2 Micro, Inc.'  (string)
  usb_device.vendor_id = 2967  (0xb97)  (int)
  usb_device.version = 1.1 (1.1) (double)

udi = '/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_b97_7761_noserial_if0'
  info.linux.driver = 'hub'  (string)
  info.parent = '/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_b97_7761_noserial'  (string)
  info.product = 'USB Hub Interface'  (string)
  info.subsystem = 'usb'  (string)
  info.udi = '/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_b97_7761_noserial_if0'  (string)
  linux.hotplug_type = 2  (0x2)  (int)
  linux.subsystem = 'usb'  (string)
  linux.sysfs_path = '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb7/7-1/7-1:1.0'  (string)
  usb.bus_number = 7  (0x7)  (int)
  usb.can_wake_up = true  (bool)
  usb.configuration_value = 1  (0x1)  (int)
  usb.device_class = 9  (0x9)  (int)
  usb.device_protocol = 0  (0x0)  (int)
  usb.device_revision_bcd = 272  (0x110)  (int)
  usb.device_subclass = 0  (0x0)  (int)
  usb.interface.class = 9  (0x9)  (int)
  usb.interface.number = 0  (0x0)  (int)
  usb.interface.protocol = 0  (0x0)  (int)
  usb.interface.subclass = 0  (0x0)  (int)
  usb.is_self_powered = true  (bool)
  usb.linux.device_number = 2  (0x2)  (int)
  usb.linux.sysfs_path = '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb7/7-1/7-1:1.0'  (string)
  usb.max_power = 2  (0x2)  (int)
  usb.num_configurations = 1  (0x1)  (int)
  usb.num_interfaces = 1  (0x1)  (int)
  usb.num_ports = 4  (0x4)  (int)
  usb.product = 'USB Hub Interface'  (string)
  usb.product_id = 30561  (0x7761)  (int)
  usb.speed = 12.0 (12) (double)
  usb.vendor = 'O2 Micro, Inc.'  (string)
  usb.vendor_id = 2967  (0xb97)  (int)
  usb.version = 1.1 (1.1) (double)

udi = '/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_b97_7772_noserial'
  info.linux.driver = 'usb'  (string)
  info.parent = '/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_b97_7761_noserial'  (string)
  info.product = 'OZ776 CCID Smartcard Reader'  (string)
  info.subsystem = 'usb_device'  (string)
  info.udi = '/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_b97_7772_noserial'  (string)
  info.vendor = 'O2 Micro, Inc.'  (string)
  linux.device_file = '/dev/bus/usb/007/004'  (string)
  linux.hotplug_type = 2  (0x2)  (int)
  linux.subsystem = 'usb'  (string)
  linux.sysfs_path = '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb7/7-1/7-1.2'  (string)
  usb_device.bus_number = 7  (0x7)  (int)
  usb_device.can_wake_up = true  (bool)
  usb_device.configuration_value = 1  (0x1)  (int)
  usb_device.device_class = 0  (0x0)  (int)
  usb_device.device_protocol = 0  (0x0)  (int)
  usb_device.device_revision_bcd = 272  (0x110)  (int)
  usb_device.device_subclass = 0  (0x0)  (int)
  usb_device.is_self_powered = true  (bool)
  usb_device.linux.device_number = 4  (0x4)  (int)
  usb_device.linux.sysfs_path = '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb7/7-1/7-1.2'  (string)
  usb_device.max_power = 0  (0x0)  (int)
  usb_device.num_configurations = 1  (0x1)  (int)
  usb_device.num_interfaces = 1  (0x1)  (int)
  usb_device.num_ports = 0  (0x0)  (int)
  usb_device.product = 'OZ776 CCID Smartcard Reader'  (string)
  usb_device.product_id = 30578  (0x7772)  (int)
  usb_device.speed = 12.0 (12) (double)
  usb_device.vendor = 'O2 Micro, Inc.'  (string)
  usb_device.vendor_id = 2967  (0xb97)  (int)
  usb_device.version = 1.1 (1.1) (double)
```

[Integrated modem](http://dell.com/us/dfb/p/latitude-d630/pd) is:

```
 Dell Wireless 5520 Mobile Broadband (Tri-band HSDPA 3.6) Mini-Card with service from AT&T (US) and 
Vodafone (select countries in Europe) Dell Wireless 5720 Mobile Broadband 
(EVDO Rev A) Mini-Card with service from Verizon Wireless (US), Sprint (US) and Telus (Canada)
```

External is: `T-Mobile ip wireless ue pcmmcia v3 tx`

Comment: What's you modem?

Comment: Integrated is:
<pre>
Dell Wireless 5520 Mobile Broadband (Tri-band HSDPA 3.6) Mini-Card with service from AT&T (US) and Vodafone (select countries in Europe) Dell Wireless 5720 Mobile Broadband (EVDO Rev A) Mini-Card with service from Verizon Wireless (US), Sprint (US) and Telus (Canada)
</pre>
http://www.dell.com/us/dfb/p/latitude-d630/pd

External is:
T-Mobile ip wireless ue pcmmcia v3 tx

Answer (score 1):

Here is a program to manage 3g connections download it and save it to to your home folder, do not rename it.

You will need this

```
sudo apt-get install qt-sdk
```

It is 500mb so make sure you have enough 3g

Once this finnished run these one line at a time

```
tar xzvf umtsmon-0.9.i386.tar.gz
cd umtsmon-0.9
qmake
make clean all
lrelease umtsmon.pro
```

This will install it, find umtsmon in the dash.

Some thing else I found is http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=787777

I searched everywhere on the net and didnt find any info, managed to figure it out myself. Therefore since i couldn't find anything i decided to share my experience in the hopes of helping someone else out.

this what I did on my dell d630
download and install the [betavine vodafone driver for linux](https://developer.vodafone.com/labs/opensource/linux-connection-manager/broadband-connection-manager/)

then in the terminal

```
"sudo lsusb -v | less"
```

look at the devices, its a long list scroll down till you find the internal card, Mine looks like this:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:8137 Dell Computer Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
bLength 18
bDescriptorType 1
bcdUSB 1.10
bDeviceClass 0 (Defined at Interface level)
bDeviceSubClass 0 
bDeviceProtocol 0 
bMaxPacketSize0 64
idVendor 0x413c Dell Computer Corp.
idProduct 0x8137 
bcdDevice 0.00
iManufacturer 1 Novatel Wireless
iProduct 2 Novatel Wireless HSDPA Modem
iSerial 2 Novatel Wireless HSDPA Modem
bNumConfigurations 1
Configuration Descriptor:
bLength 9
```

then once you have done that take note of the id vendor and id product value.

thne type in the terminal

`sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x413c product=0x8115`

Insert your own idproduct and idvendor number in the vendor and product fields that you previously took note of

then

```
`grep tty /var/log/messages`
```

and check to see if the output says the modem is attatched to ttyUSB1 0r ttyUSB0

now launch the vodafone driver for linux

when presented with the device set up, choose serial in the drop down list and in the two entry fields typt `ttyUSB0` or `ttyUSB1` depending on where the modem is attatched ie look at the output of

```
grep tty /var/log/messages
```

I hope some1 found this valuable and i saved someone hours of frustration

Peace out!

one more thing to make sure the devices is activated at boot:

```
"sudo gedit /etc/modules"
```

add to the end of file

```
echo usbserial vendor=0x4XXX product=0x81XX
```

(X = your specifiv vendor and prouct ID)

Comment: thank you, i will try it. Is there any reason, why you write about umtsmon v0.8, because there is newest version 0.9 stable and 0.10alpha2.

Comment: Please use version 9 if you can, 8 was just what I use for my example, I will update the code for version 9 for you

Comment: Sry, Mark, I don't know what argument(s) I muset fill with qmake command. Because when I type `qmake` in Terminal I obtain --help display message.

Comment: I try run binary locally, without install and have error:
`error while loading shared libraries libqt-mt.so.3`
I found on Google, that qt3 library is missing??

Comment: Please try just make instead of qmake you must install the qt-sdk

Comment: I have succesfully installed umtsmon 0.9 by this tutorial http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=868886 (choose convert rpm file to deb by alien). But still in system is missing libqt-mt.so.3.

I try to type `make` command insteed qmake and obtain this erors: http://i61.tinypic.com/mjbaty.jpg

Comment: Here it is as a .deb file http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/libqt3-mt/download

Comment: UMTSmon are running (libqt3-mt was only one required by the app). But if my SIM card is in internal 3G modem or in external, still in application is blink msg: "No device (yet)".. AND yes, 3G is working... (in Windows 7)

Comment: Please clarify, If you open the UMTSmon GUI you get blink msg: "No device (yet)"

Comment: yes, GUI show msg: "No device (yet)" with SIM card with internal 3G modem and also in external modem

Comment: I cannot download BCM (betavine from vodafone), https links are detah and SVN source cannot compile, there is reason (error): http://goo.gl/egQJcY

Comment: You have two unmet dependencies `python-central` and `python-setuptools` so you can not compile the pyton based package, install instruction for python are here http://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-do-i-install-python-3-3

Comment: I am not sure what steps next. I was downloaded via svn source code of BCM again, install these mentioned two dependencies (python 3.3 is not neccesary) and now I get this log:
http://goo.gl/XgDEt4
and now I can't read any usefull informations from this log what next. Deb package was not created.

Comment: It should now be installed on your computer, look in the dash for betavine or try `betavine` or `BCM` in terminal, if not where did you find the install instructions something was uploaded somewhere but I can not see where.