# Python 3.3 installation error - abort installation

Tags: apt, python, python3

When I try to upgrade `python3` version, I am getting the following error

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  autoconf blt blt-dev debhelper dh-apparmor diffstat gettext html2text
  intltool-debian libbluetooth-dev libdb5.1-dev libffi-dev libfontconfig1-dev
  libfreetype6-dev libgdbm-dev libgettextpo0 libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore
  libncursesw5-dev libreadline-dev libreadline6-dev libtinfo-dev libunistring0
  libxext-dev libxft-dev libxrender-dev libxss-dev libxss1 m4 po-debconf
  python-sphinx quilt sharutils sphinx-common tcl8.5 tcl8.5-dev tk8.5
  tk8.5-dev x11proto-render-dev x11proto-scrnsaver-dev x11proto-xext-dev xvfb
0 upgraded, 42 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 16.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 53.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Abort.
```

Why am I getting aborted? I referred this [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/250056/550121) to upgrade python3.

I would like to remove python 3.2 after installing 3.3 version

**Edit 1:**

Also tried with <kbd>Y</kbd> (capital y). But not working.

Comment: maybe try with upper case `Y`?

Comment: Also tried it. but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what was the error. But now I have succeeded the above problem.

What I have done is,

Step 1) Restarted my PC

2) Ran the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.3.2/Python-3.3.2.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf ./Python-3.3.2.tar.bz2
cd ./Python-3.3.2
./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.3
make && make install
mkdir ~/bin
ln -s /opt/python3.3/bin/python ~/bin/py
echo 'alias py="/opt/python3.3/bin/python3"' >> .bashrc
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install build-essential libncursesw5-dev libreadline-dev libssl-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev
sudo apt-get build-dep python3.2
```

And then it is now installed. But still can't install the virtualenv. And have raised as a new question in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/q/783800/550121)