# When is LibreOffice 4.0 coming to Ubuntu 12.10 as an update?

Tags: 12.10, libreoffice

Is LibreOffice 4.0 coming to Ubuntu 12.10 as an update? If so when?

There is no Deb package to upgrade that one can just double click to install LO 4.0. The present instructions given on some websites are quite complicated.

Thank you.

:)

Comment: The answers here should explain: http://askubuntu.com/questions/95336/why-cant-i-update-applications-without-upgrading-the-whole-os and are worth reading even though they don't address your specific question.

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LibreOffice 4.0 is a major release, and hence may not be available in Ubuntu 12.10 via Software Updater (reason already mentioned by @vasa1 in a comment to your question, I'd recommend to read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/95350/12242) of the same thread).

But if you're still interested in installing LO 4.0 in your box, [WebUp8's Guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/libreoffice-40-available-for-download.html) should get that done (and I don't think process explained there is *that* complicated). ;-)

And if its still complex for you, let's make it easier FTW. Here you go.

If you're using any previous versions of LO4 (Beta, RC, etc.) Better you follow up the link I've provided above ('cause you're already brave then). If not, do as follows.

- Grab appropriate `.deb` installer (technically, it'll be a `.tar` archive) for your version of Ubuntu [here](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/?nodetect).
- The one you downloaded is one giant TAR archive (~160+ MBs), and now real work starts.
- Go to your `home` folder and create a new folder called `libreoffice` and put that TAR file in here. Now open terminal using short-cut Ctrl+Alt+T and navigate to `libreoffice` folder by running command `cd libreoffice`.
- Now extract the archive by running `tar xvf libreoffice_downloaded_file.tar` (be sure to replace with actual file name you've downloaded.
- Once extraction is done, run following command to install `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`. It'll ask for password and once installation is done, exit terminal and look for LibreOffice 4 apps in Unity Dash.

Cheers. :-)