# Why traditional ubuntu apps never check for new updates

Tags: updates, software-center

Why ubuntu software centre, which is the app store for ubuntu never show about application updates which is one of the basic app store functionality?

[Why can't I update applications without upgrading the whole OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95336/why-cant-i-update-applications-without-upgrading-the-whole-os)

I know that's why they brought snap apps and snap store. But it has its limitations. Instead of that, isn't that good that bringing a stable release  update app feature? What they haven't come up with yet? We have to check manually for new updates and the software centre  doesn't. How can we know when new updates will come? [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: Are you aware that ["Software Properties"](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/software-properties-gtk) lets you upgrade software? (It doesn't sound like you're asking the advanced question which muru and Ferdi are attempting to answer.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They do for some select applications, such as Firefox. But otherwise it is by design.

There is nothing stopping you to install new "stable" releases of other packages in an LTS version of Ubuntu, if you have the knowledge to do so. But they will not be published in the official repositories for your version.

You either have to:

- Add a dedicated software repository for the desired software (often maintained by the software developer)
- Use snaps/appimage/flatpack
- Download and compile the software yourself

All of these methods require some skill and could compromise your system or change the look and usage of the software.

If you want it the way you propose, you should consider using a rolling release distribution, like Arch or Manjaro

Comment: Yes. We can use terminal for cheking and installing updates. But the software centre never notices us about it like the play store and appstore does. It is the basic functionality of an app store. How can we know when new updates will come?

Comment: @ArjunVK Do you mean that the software app doesn't notify you of package updates? Elementary's AppCenter (and other downstream forks like the Pop!_Shop) do this, and I thought the default software app for Ubuntu had the feature. Have you disabled it?

Comment: @Ferdi You might be overthinking the question. If I understand, the OP is not asking why Ubuntu packages can only be upgraded to a certain point; OP is asking, can they be upgraded *at all*.

Comment: @Jpaugh well, yes they can and do. Every Ubuntu version checks at least once per day for updates. When there are some, they are either implemented in the background, downloaded and notified to the user, or only notified, all based on user setting. The software center does also have an "Updates" button to display all available updates to the user.